# goerli hardhat deploy and test hung

Tags: hardhat-deploy, alchemy, goerli

We have been trying to deploy contracts and run tests against them on the goerli network.  For the past few days, the network seems unusable.  Transactions doesn't come back.  Contracts deployment using hardhat is showing pending forever.  Does anyone know if there are problems with the goerli network?

Here is our hardhat.config.js for the goerli network:

```
goerli: {
  url: 'https://eth-goerli.g.alchemy.com/v2/my-api-key',
  accounts: [`0x${privateKey}`]
},
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override pending transactions and override them with new transactions by resetting the nonce and may need to adjust your gas. Take a look at this post for possible solutions:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/tj6liu/are_your_transactions_or_deployments_hanging_in/